# My div won't align in Firefox (works in Chrome & Safari)

Tags: php, html, css

I am losing the will to live! I am an amateur coder so nothing special but I am trying my best.

I have a page here:
http://www.simplypsychics.com/null/OnlineReaders.php

In Chrome, it works. In Safari it works. In Firefox, the white bit shoots to the right.

Please can anyone tell me why my div is moved?

This is my CSS code:
http://www.simplypsychics.com/null/OnlineReaders.css

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: No, you posted a link to it. You should always post your code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `clear: left;` instead of `float: left` on this selector: `#feed li`

Comment: Something so so simple! Thank you so much.

Comment: What does "better" mean?

Answer (score 0):

In your this css class .readwhite, in firefox the
remove the position: absolute;

So the css for .readwhite would be

```
#feed .readerwhite {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    float: left;
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    margin-top: -140px;
    width: 246px;
}
```